# Show that $\mu (\left[a, b\right)) = \ln \frac{1 + b}{1+a}$ (a measure on $X = [0,1]$) is invariant wrt. $x \rightarrow \left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, invariance

Show that  $\mu (\left[a, b\right)) = \ln \frac{1 + b}{1+a}$ (a measure on $X = [0,1]$) is invariant wrt. $x \rightarrow \left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}$

---

My question here is: What does it mean, that a measure is invariant with respect to a map/function? And how can we show it here on this example, especially as we're dealing with a mapping which goes from $x \rightarrow \left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}$ (where $\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}$ is the mantissa of $\frac{1}{x}$).

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1/x$.  Is $\mu([a,b)) = \mu(f([a,b)))$ for all $[a,b) \in [0,1]$?

Comment: So it's just writing it out and comparing it? But how should I deal with the mantissa here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$T(x) = \{\frac{1}{x} \}$ invariant measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530812/tx-frac1x-invariant-measure)

Comment: @JeanMarie No, because the solution there requires using some sort of transfer operator, which we haven't done at all.

Comment: Have you seen the reference given by AJY there ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530812/tx-frac1x-invariant-measure ?

Comment: Google queries with "Gauss' measure" keyword provide a lot of information, for example this (historical) question and its answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23305/how-did-gauss-discover-the-invariant-density-for-the-gauss-map